# validating between 2 textboxes - jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, datetime

how i do validate two date textboxes using jquery. i came across this snippet of code. how do i enter the textbox parameters:

```
$.validator.addMethod('greaterThan', function(value, element, param) { return ( IsNaN( value ) && IsNaN( $(param).val() ) ) || ( value > $(param).val() ); }, 'Must be greater than {0}.' );

$.validator.addMethod('lesserThan', function(value, element, param) { return ( IsNaN( value ) && IsNaN( $(param).val() ) ) || ( value < $(param).val() ); }, 'Must be lesser than {0}.' );
```

the start date has to be greater than end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#msg").text('');

  $("#checkdates").click(function(event) {
    var startdate = Date.parse($("#startdate").val());
    if (!startdate) {
      $("#msg").append("Start Date is not a valid date<br/>");
    }

    var enddate = Date.parse($("#enddate").val());
    if (!enddate) {
      $("#msg").append("End Date is not a valid date<br/>");
    }

    if (startdate && enddate) {
      if (startdate < enddate) {
        $("#msg").text("Start date must be greater than end date");
      } else {
        $("#msg").text("all good!");
      }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Start: <input type="text" id="startdate" value="1/1/2000" />
  End: <input type="text" id="enddate" value="1/1/1990" />
</form>
<button id="checkdates">Check Dates</button>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

Grab DateJS

http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: it's not throwing any error. where do i add the function validateDates()?

and what if i want to display the error in label format instead of alert [messagebox]?

Comment: there are many ways to do it, but I dont have much info other than what you posted in your question, this code works ... but I can't read your mind

Comment: you've given the validation on the button click event. but i'd like the error label to be displayed as soon as the user enters the wrong date/the end date is lesser than the start date.

Comment: i'd have thought that the code which posted in the question would have been easier to implement had i known how to modify it accordingly - ie, to get the values of the textbox and compare and validate.